# Is WIRA, “water filtered Infrared A”, therapy effective on warts?

Tags: medical-science

Is water-filtered infrared A therapy effective on warts? If not, what is just as good or better? (And is it a waste of time and money?)

My dermatologist here in Germany, having felt that application of salicylic acid was not having the desired effect on warts on my toes has started me on a course of “WIRA-Therapie”, or water-filtered infrared A therapy. Curious, I looked for it on de.wikipedia and found that it had been removed from the article on warts after [an extensive discussion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion:Warze/Archiv#Abschnitt_Wassergefiltertes_Infrarot_A_entfernt) and that [a general article on WIRA treatment had been deleted](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassergefiltertes_Infrarot_A), along with the discussion page, making the latter source useless. I have found nothing about it on en.WP. I found the following publications:

- (in German) http://www.gesundheits-lexikon.com/Aesthetische-Medizin/Warzentherapie-wIRA-Methode/ , a sober sounding introduction for the layman.
- (in German) http://www.uni-jena.de/uni_journal_1_2003_Medizin_2.html#med_3 (2009-09-17 or earlier), where the method is announced.
- (in English) http://europepmc.org/articles/PMC2703213 *Photodynamic therapy (PDT) and waterfiltered infrared A (wIRA) in patients with recalcitrant common hand and foot warts* (Silke M. Fuchs, Joachim W. Fluhr, Lora Bankova, Jörg Tittelbach, Gerd Hoffmann und Peter Elsner) in *German Medical Science*, apparently the original publication.

  - They claim 42% vs. 7% complete cures and 72% vs. 34% vanished warts with and without WIRA respectively.
  - I *think* the control groups were irradiated with visible light instead of WIRA, but that is not clear to me.

My impression of the de.WP discussion on the *Warze* page is that many felt it insufficiently established; they felt, I think, that no-one had reproduced the results and/or that the research was well described but did not support the conclusions and/or that the work was of low quality. What I did not find was a survey of relevant publications and how relevant authorities judged them. The method also seems far less known in anglophone countries.

Someone claimed that 1,000 in 4,000 German dermatologists apply it; this does very little to establish its validity (unless they conduct trials), but makes an answer that much more desirable.

I imagine that the effects of water filtering (e.g. reduction in infrared B) could be achieved in other ways, but the point is not how the spectrum is produced but what effect it has.

Comment: 1000 out of 4000 German Dermatologists means zip.  German doctors are also quite likely to prescribe homeopathic treatments, and you know how well regarded that is outside of Germany.

Comment: Search for info on "Infrared coagulation" and warts.  That'll turn up more information.  I expect you aren't finding much because the term you use (wira) is more typical for the German publications.

Comment: The "water filtered" part is quite possibly the source of the difficulty in finding good information.  I expect that to be attributed to the German love of "natural" methods of treatment.  Infrared isn't good enough by itself, its got to be made "natural" by filtering it through water.

Comment: @JRE: As I said in the question, 1,000/4,000 dermatologists means little but makes an answer more desirable. Thank-you for the other suggestions; if no-one who knows more weighs in I may use them to seek further. I find “_natural_” a reason for heightened suspicion because it appeals to confused or simplistic thinking, yet organisms ought to have a good chance of coping with conditions they are evolved to deal with — evidence is the only satisfactory answer!